# compare and find in a collection

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

i'm a actually struggling with mongoDb collection and asp.net core.

previously, i made an async function to getall the movies owned by the user's compagny, but i wanted to change that for the user to be able to be in mutliple differents compagnies.

Compagny compagny contains a public string[] compagnyNames;

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Film>>> GetAllFilms([FromBody] Compagny compagny)
        {
            var toReturn = await _filmCollection.Find(item => item.CompagnyOwner == compagny.CompagnyName[0]).ToListAsync();
            return Ok(toReturn);
        }
```

I can't find a way to checks all the movies from all compagnies, here i can only get the movies owned by compagnyName[0] and not all of them.

Do you guys know a simple way to pass through all the strings contained in Compagny compagny?

I'm a junior so maybe i'm not very clear.

Feel free to ask precisions.

thanks!

Comment: *...all the strings **contained** in...* so maybe  `System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
var toReturn = await _filmCollection.Find(item => compagny.CompagnyName.Contains(item.CompagnyOwner)).ToListAsync();
```